# bluetooth beacon rules, spec type questions

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, response, beacon

I am new to BLE beacons, and playing with some ideas and I can find lots of examples of data formats, but not much info about scan requests and responses.

I have some questions about "scanable beacons", what's allowed and what is not allowed. I sort of want the beacon to operate in two modes.

I see that the SCAN REQUEST is fixed - they don't seem to include a payload that describes what the SCANNER wants.

Are scan responses fixed?

Basically - without forming a connection

If my tablet app sees a specific UUID in a beacon, I want it to send a scan request to the device requesting more information, the response information I want to send won't fit inside the beacon payload. I can fragment it - but that seems like the wrong idea.

Suggestions?

The second part of the question is making the beacon modal, in the normal sense the beacon transmits every 5 seconds.

Then when the app is near by, it switches to more frequent rate, and interleaves other types of beacons. The near by app would - for example send a "I am here" message - Eventually if the human walks away after a period of time (20seconds?) the beacon goes back to the slow rate.

Answer (score 0):

Scan request has defined format and does not include any custom payload. It contains only 2 fields (both 6 bytes long): TxAddr and RxAddr. You can not send anything to your device together with scan request PDU.

Scan response also has predefined format but may include custom payload (up to 32 bytes).

Comment: How often do scan requests occur...  I'm thinking I might be able to make my device "modal" in this way.  - Every 5 to 10 seconds send out a beacon with only a UUID - my application can look for the UUID beacon.  My application can then do a scan request.  My device would then respond to the scan request in the standard way, but then switch into a "more frequent mode" interleaving multiple beacons with lots of 'vendor specific data'. This might last for 30 seconds... then return to normal.  What will screw me is things continuously send ScanRequests.. Thoughts?

Comment: As wrote below scan request usually send by BT controller when it received first advertisement packet.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth LE beacons largely conform to a standard set of behavior:

- Transmit only devices sending one or more advertising packets at 10Hz to 0.1 Hz.
- Avertisements send out a  standard format (iBeacon, AltBeacon, Eddystone variants)
- Scan responses are not always supported, but when they are it is typically sending out the fixed beacon name in ASCII.
  " May be connectable to use proprietary Bluetooth GATT configuration or other services.

No off-the shelf Bluetooth LE beacons do what you want

It is of course possible to build a custom Bluetooth LE device that has standard beconing features plus the extra features you  want.  That said, you will likely have to use connections (or BLE scanning of  external advertisements initiated from mobile devices) to signal ro your custom BLE beacon device to support these features.  This is because a scan request packet has no data fields as @mike-petrichenko says in his answer.  You will need to use something else to command your custom beacon.

Comment: I understand scan responses are *typically* fixed - but Do scan responses need to be fixed? Can I interleave multiple responses, all with various vendor specific data.

Comment: While scan responses do not need to be fixed, they are controlled at the bluetooth controller level, so when you tell the controller what to advertise, you also tell it what to send as the scan response.   To change, this, you must interleave at some time interval.   The problem is that BLE centrals typically send ONE request for a scan response when the first advertisement is received.   Many mobile and desktop platforms like iOS, Android, MacOS allow some control over BLE advertising and peripheral mode, but do not allow control over the scan response. iOS apps cannot read the scan response.